How to host Selenium on AWS with a non-headless Chrome browser instance for users?
I am trying to build a bot that automates an hour long training course for my college for students to use.
I was originally going to host the bot on AWS but I do not want the app to run in headless mode and would like for students to actually see a browser going through the tutorial in realtime.  So far I have only found ways to run selenium on the cloud in headless mode.
Does anyone know if there’s a way to run selenium on AWS without running it in headless mode?
I have also considered running the selenium as a downloadable desktop app.  Is this potentially a better idea?
